# MongoDB: How to "union all" results from same collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

query.1:

```
db.test.find({category_id:1}).sort({createAt:-1}).limit(5);
```

query.2:

```
db.test.find({category_id:2}).sort({createAt:-1}).limit(5);
```

What I want is use one query get results of query1+query2, and then sort the results by `createAt`.

Comment: db.test.find({$or:[{category_id:2},{category_id:2}]).sort({createAt:-1}).limit(5);

or

db.test.find({category_id:{$in:[1,2]}}).sort({createAt:-1}).limit(5);

Comment: @matthPen In this way, it is possible that I get 7 entries from category 1 and 3 entries from category 2. What I want is same number entries from each category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation here.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "first": [
      { "$match": { "category_id": 1 }},
      { "$sort": { "createAt": -1 }},
      { "$limit": 5 }
    ],
    "second": [
      { "$match": { "category_id": 2 }},
      { "$sort": { "createAt": -1 }},
      { "$limit": 5 }
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": { "data": { "$concatArrays": ["$first", "$second"] }}},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

**Update**

Using simple javascript

```
const test1 = await db.test.find({ category_id: 1 }).sort({ createAt: -1 }).limit(5)

const test2 = await db.test.find({ category_id: 1 }).sort({ createAt: -1 }).limit(5)

const test = test1.concat(test2)

console.log(test)
```

Comment: I can get the right result using this query. But it doesn't use my Index({category_id:1,createAt:-1}), and run very slow(around 2 second on a 1million docs collection). If I use general find().sort().limit(), it will use index and run fast(0.001 second)

Comment: `$facet` aggregation does not use the index. You have to manually concat the arrays using javascript. I have updated my answer