# Combine 2 collections into a single collection mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections in mongoDB

collection 1

```
  {
    _id : "123",
    name : "ABC1"
  }
```

collection 2

```
  {
    _id : "456",
    name : "DEF1"
  }
```

I'm trying to combine write a query that gives me an output like so

**Output**

```
  [
    {
      _id : "123",
      name : "ABC1"
    },
    {
     _id : "456",
     name : "DEF1"
    }
  ]
```

I've tried lookup but that seems to append 1 collection to the other, I want the collections to be merged like shown in the output.
I have looked at the existing solutions on stack overflow and they all suggest using `lookup` which does not give me the output that I require.

Comment: you can make two separate queries and then combine and return responses using [...res1, ...res2]

Comment: @AZ_ I could do that but I also would like to perform pagination and conditional queries on the existing query, so for example I would like to fetch only the first 10 entries where the name matches "abc" with a given sort order on the name field, this could also be individually done on each query and combined but the results would not be in the correct order.

Comment: Those should actually be in the same collection then?

Comment: @JonasWilms there are actually more fields in each collection, I've skipped those for brevity, these were the fields that I needed to focus on that were common between the 2 collections. If I were to give an example, I would say collection 1 could be a collection of physical books and collection 2 would be of audio books and I want to return a list of all books in the system, irrespective of it being physical or virtual.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400979/mongodb-how-to-union-all-results-from-same-collection/55403004#55403004

Answer (score 0):

Make two independent queries and combine them:

```
const output = [query1, query2];
```

Comment: I could do that but I also would like to perform pagination and conditional queries on the existing query, so for example I would like to fetch only the first 10 entries where the name matches "abc" with a given sort order on the name field, this could also be individually done on each query and combined but the results would not be in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through `javascript` code on mongo shell as follow:

```
> var all = []; // initialize a variable with empty values

> db.collection1.find().forEach(function (obj) {all.push(obj);}) // push to all from collection 1

> db.collection2.find().forEach(function (obj) {all.push(obj);}) // push to all from collection 2

> printjson(all) // Print all pushed elements 
[
    {
        "_id" : "123",
        "name" : "ABC1"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "456",
        "name" : "DEF1"
    }
]
```

Hope this will help you. You can perform this on mongo shell.